# How to mount C drive of windows on any linux machine

Tags: linux, windows

I want to mount my windows machine C drive on a Linux machine

Can we do it, open for suggestions too

or anyway through linux terminal

This is not dual booted, completely different machines

Comment: Why tag it Windows? You don't want to know anything about Windows.

Comment: You can take the physical drive containing the C volume and connect it to a Linux machine like any other drive. Then you mount the filesystem. What have you tried? Is your question because you think the operation may be unsafe, destructive or what? Is your question because the setup is kinda complicated? RAID, encryption or what? Or do you want to remotely mount the C volume of another machine while the machine is running Windows from this very volume?

Comment: Many ways, e.g. as external USB drive, inserting in Linux box... be specific.